# SSRS 2008R2 how to auto refresh from one report to another

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i have created a report in SSRS 2008 R2, i want my report to auto refresh after every 30 seconds but it must display different reports. I know how to do a Auto refresh but how can i display different report everytime the report refreshes

Comment: Let us know the base line/rule to show different report on every refresh.

Comment: the rule should be, every 30 seconds it refreshes to a new report, i have separated my reports using a page break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gurru, the logic to define what report should be displayed must be in some component inside/outside RS. I see 2 ways to achieve that:

1. Build a master report, with n subreports, and turn each subreport
   visible/invisible based on current time, creating a hide parameter
   whose value changes over time.
2. Build an ASP.NET page/control, with n ReportViewer, one for each
       subreport, and control which one to show using a timer.